# Copy HTML from an original document into a popup window (using JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, copy, clone

This is my first post to stack overflow,... :)  I like this site a lot!

My question: How do I copy an element from an opening page into a popup window using JQuery?

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
CopyToThisPageFromTheParent('#accordianResults');
function CopyToThisPageFromTheParent(querySelector) {
    var clone = $(querySelector, window.parent.document).clone();
    $('#testHtml').append(clone);
    alert($('#testHtml').html());
}
```

I've also tried:

```
    var clone = $('#accordianResults', window.parent.document).clone();
    alert($('#testHtml').html());
```

Thanks!

David

Comment: I got this code working, so I guess I should mark it as an answer below so I can show you what I ended up doing?

Comment: You mark the correct answer with a checkmark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had two problems with my JavaScript.

1. I was using window.parent.document instead of
   window.opener.document
2. For some reason the .append() syntax would not allow me to append
   the cloned object

Instead I had to use the .html() item hanging off of the JQuery selector to pass HTML out of the clone and into .append().

Here is the eventual end result:

```
CopyToThisPageFromTheParent('#accordion', '#testDiv');

function CopyToThisPageFromTheParent(openingWindowSelector, childWindowSelector) {
     var clone = $(openingWindowSelector, window.opener.document).clone(true);
     var theOuterHtml = clone.wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
     $(childWindowSelector).append(theOuterHtml);
}
```

This is assuming I have this HTML:

```
<div id="testDiv"></div>
```

on my popup window's page, and this HTML:

```
<div id="accordion">something</div>
```

in my main page, and used "`window.open();`" to open up the popup window.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
$("#testHtml").html($(querySelector).html())
```

Comment: Actually, thanks locrizak, that is what I needed! (using the .html() property to populate it.)

Comment: This will only populate it with the *children* of the target of `queryselector`

Comment: True, it still needs to reference the originating page (window.opener.document)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this is about:

`$(querySelector, window.parent.document)`

$ will select from the entire DOM by default. That is functionally identical to:

`$(querySelector)`

Your code, actually, looks like it should work, assuming the selectors are correct for things on your page.

Comment: Hi Jamietre, This is a popup window running in the context of a window.open() command.  I actually had the syntax wrong.  It should be: $(querySelector, window.parent.document); it seems.

Comment: $(querySelector, window.opener.document);

Comment: that makes more sense, i was wondering what the heck you were trying to do!